# How can I make a pixelated non-straight border in CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have some elements I'd like to display in a project I'm working on. Each of them is supposed to look like a pixelated banner, sort of. Here's an example:

[image: asdfasdfsadfasd]

The straight lines on the left and right are easy. Those are just simple borders. The bottom of the banner is the difficult part. I would like for this to be able to adjust kind of like a flex object would. This requirement is making it very difficult to find a solution. The pixels need to remain the same size and so it seems like an svg wouldn't work.

I spent a decent amount of time googling last night and I found some solutions, but none seemed to be adjustable. They were static sizes with pixel manipulations to get the effect.

Can anyone think of how to achieve this effect? Just being pointed in the right direction would be wonderful as well.

Comment: Create 5 "rows" using divs, set only border left/right, center them, and adjust the size to match your picture

Comment: https://github.com/43081j/pixelate.js take a look at this lib

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) property might help you. You'll need a static image with of your pixel border to be sliced at the appropriate places.

You could also try [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) for curving the border, if the solution you're using now would work with that.

Comment: `border-radius` won't work, just off the top of my head.